# How to take 5 km points in all directions of a location, geocoding google api?

Tags: google-maps, geocode, google-geocoder

Ok so i have these cords:

```
55.623151, 8.48215
```

I would like to see the geo codes 5 km from north, south, east, west from this geo location above^.

How can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean by geo codes? Lat/lng coordinates?

Comment: @Jiri yes that is what i mean

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you use Google Maps API v3, then  you would proceed as follows:

Include the Geometry library into your Web page for [Spherical Computations](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#spherical):

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"> 
</script>
```

Then you can compute:

```
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(55.623151, 8.48215);
var spherical = google.maps.geometry.spherical; 
var north = spherical.computeOffset(point, 5000, 0); 
var west  = spherical.computeOffset(point, 5000, -90); 
var south = spherical.computeOffset(point, 5000, 180); 
var east  = spherical.computeOffset(point, 5000, 90);
```

You can check a [running version on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KSAMz/).

Comment: When i try to var north = computeOffset(point, 5000, 0); 
    alert('test:' +north); i get no alert at all? not even test: ...

Comment: @Karem: the geometry functions need to be qualified. I updated my answer correspondingly.

Comment: @Karem: I added a [running program](http://jsfiddle.net/KSAMz/). When you have problems with spherical, then use `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(point, 5000, 0);`